# Which one of displayed formula below does not represent an isomer of heptane?

Tags: hydrocarbons

All of these appeared to be correct. I’ve already counted their hydrogen and carbon number. Please help!

[[image]1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnQvO.jpg

Comment: (D) is n-heptane only. So, it should be the answer.

Comment: If you were ever asked to count the total number of structural isomers of heptane, you will definitely count n-heptane as one of them. However, this question has explicitly drawn what "heptane" looks like (actually it's n-heptane), and then asks you to identify which of the following is NOT an isomer of "heptane". Clearly, option D is not an isomer of  "heptane", rather "heptane" itself. Hence, D.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Is it because D’s vertical chain isn’t less than D’s horizontal chain.

Comment: @user28603 It is a single unbroken carbon chain of seven atoms...

Comment: @GaurangTandon So you're saying that the structure drawn in D is the principle chain of Heptane. The structure that is above the question isn't the principle chain of Heptane. Am I right?

Comment: @user28603 Both the structures (one drawn above the question and the option D) are *same* (and yes, both are unbranched, n-heptane). But, option D is drawn in a way to make it _look_ different from the other one.  See carefully.

Comment: @user28603 You should try to use ball and stick models to visualize better... https://www.amazon.com/Molecular-Model-Organic-Inorganic-Chemistry/dp/B016XJN2G0

Answer (score 2):

The structure in the question and option (D) are the same thing. Note that a *branching* as apparently seems is not a real branch on the principle chain that would give an isomer. Basically (D) is same as that given in the question.

Comment: But a, b, c, d’s amounts of hydrocarbons are the same right?

Comment: @user28603 I didn't get it.What do you mean by amount of hydrocarbons?

Comment: Amount of Hydrogen and Carbon.

Comment: @user28603 Yes. The *amount* is same as structural formula is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The option d should be correct since the name of the compound is the same as the given in the question... 
They are homomers